# Vue - Toggle state from external click

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

- I have a v-for loop of buttons (**on click, the active state is toggled**),
- and then I have a separate button '**X Clear Filters**', that resets my data.

What I can't figure out, is how to set the current "active" states to false when I click the 'X Clear Filters' button.

I have tried putting `isClicked = false`, in the `clearAllData` **method**, but that didn't work out.

Any tips or solutions would be a great help. Thank you!

I have the following set up:

```
    <button v-for="catButton in categoryFilters" :key="catButton.id" 
          class="button button--link button--filter"
          :class="{ active: catButton.isClicked }"
          @click="loadSearchData(catButton.slug, catButton.isClicked = !catButton.isClicked)"
          ref="el"
    >
                        {{ catButton.name }}
    </button>
```

I then have another button to clear those selections that follows right after:

```
    <button id="clear-all" v-on:click="clearAllData()">
          X CLEAR FILTERS
    </button>
```

My current methods for those are as follows:

```
     loadSearchData(value){
         let self = this;
         if(categoriesArray.includes(value)){
             rmh_remove(categoriesArray, value);
         } else {
             categoriesArray.push(value);
         }
         self.postsData.page = 1;
         categorieString = (categoriesArray.length > 0) ? categoriesArray.join('+') : self.$route.params.slug ;
         self.postsData['filter[category_name]'] = categorieString;
         self.getPosts();    
     },
     clearAllData(){

         console.log(this.$refs.el);
         this.postsData.page = 1;
         this.postsData['filter[category_name]'] = this.$route.params.slug;
         categorieString = this.$route.params.slug;
         categoriesArray = [];
         this.getPosts();


     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send catButton into loadSearchData as the only parameter.

```
      @click="loadSearchData(catButton)"
```

in 'loadSearchData',

```
loadSearchData(catButton){
   catButton.isClicked = !catButton.isClicked
   const value = catButton.slug
   //...
```

in clearAllData

```
clearAllData(){
   this.categoryFilters.forEach(it=>it.isClicked = false)
   //..
}
```

Comment: Worked great!  thank you! (also cleaned up that @click call, much nicer now)

I didn't even think to loop through the array